# Restore Surface Pro 4

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro-4

What button combination do I use to force a clean Windows install on a Surface Pro 4?

I’m holding volume up and power for 15 seconds and get a screen that reads Surface UEFI at the top. There are a few options there but none of them is for resetting the device.

Currently I can’t log into my device. How do I force this reset?

Comment: It’s a computer. Get a Windows installation USB drive and fire away.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a factory restore from the Windows 10 login screen. Assuming your issue is a forgotten password, you should be able to boot to the login screen, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while tapping `Restart` on the login screen.

[image]

> If your tablet doesn't have a physical keyboard, you can hold down the SHIFT key using the **On-Screen Keyboard** utility, which can be accessed by clicking the Ease of Access icon at the login screen. [image]

Once the Surface restarts, it should show the following screen:
[image]

Click `Troubleshoot`, then `Reset your PC` on the following screen.

<sup>*Images and technique via: https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/factory-reset-surface-pro-without-password.html</sup>